# Android capturing slow motion video using CamcorderProfile

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, slowmotion

I am trying to capture slow motion video on my Nexus 5x. This is how I am configuring the media recorder:

```
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH);

mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

// Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
mCamera.unlock();
mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

// Step 2: Set sources
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

// Step 3: Set the high speed CamcorderProfile
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);

// Step 4: Set output file
// Step 5: Prepare media recorder
// Step 6: Capture video
```

The problem is, the captured videos are not the 120 fps slow motion videos that my device supports. They are the regular 29 fps videos.

I went through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33170065/629663), which talks about the following in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_LOW):

> For all the high speed profiles defined below ((from
>   QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_LOW to QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_2160P), they are similar
>   as normal recording profiles, with just higher output frame rate and
>   bit rate. Therefore, setting these profiles with
>   setProfile(CamcorderProfile) without specifying any other encoding
>   parameters will produce high speed videos rather than slow motion
>   videos that have different capture and output (playback) frame rates.
>   **To record slow motion videos, the application must set video output
>   (playback) frame rate and bit rate appropriately via
>   setVideoFrameRate(int) and setVideoEncodingBitRate(int) based on the
>   slow motion factor.** If the application intends to do the video
>   recording with MediaCodec encoder, it must set each individual field
>   of MediaFormat similarly according to this CamcorderProfile.

The thing that I don't get is, [setProfile](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#422) already calls the two methods setVideoFrameRate and setVideoEncodingBitRate with parameters derived from the chosen CamcorderProfile. Why do I need to call them again? What am I missing here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. For the life of me, I cannot get this to work!

EDIT: I have tried calling the methods like so but it still captures normal speed video:

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate/4); 
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate/4);
```

1/4 since the advertised frame rate by the CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH is 120 and I want to capture a 30 fps video as stated in the document [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#videoFrameRate)

> public int videoFrameRate
>
> Added in API level 8 The target video frame rate in frames per second.
>
> This is the target recorded video output frame rate per second if the
>   application configures the video recording via
>   setProfile(CamcorderProfile) without specifying any other
>   MediaRecorder encoding parameters. For example, for high speed quality
>   profiles (from QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_LOW to QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_2160P),
>   this is the frame rate where the video is recorded and played back
>   with. If the application intends to create slow motion use case with
>   the high speed quality profiles, it must set a different video frame
>   rate that is corresponding to the desired output (playback) frame rate
>   via setVideoFrameRate(int). **For example, if QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_720P
>   advertises 240fps videoFrameRate in the CamcorderProfile, and the
>   application intends to create 1/8 factor slow motion recording videos,
>   the application must set 30fps via setVideoFrameRate(int).** Failing to
>   do so will result in high speed videos with normal speed playback
>   frame rate (240fps for above example). If the application intends to
>   do the video recording with MediaCodec encoder, it must set each
>   individual field of MediaFormat similarly according to this
>   CamcorderProfile.

Comment: Just a guess, but did you actually try to call `setVideoFrameRate` and `setVideoEncodingBitRate` manually? Did you check the values your profile is submitting?

Comment: Yes @damian, I call the following just before prepare:
 `mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate/4);`
 `mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate/4);`

The profile `videoBitRate` is `27000000` and `videoFrameRate` is `120`

Comment: Hi, @Siddharth. Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @flutillie No. Could not solve this problem. Please do comment if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @Siddharth Any solutions? Stuck in same issue.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, do you know an android camera application (third-party) which already capture at 120 fps rate? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_LOW);
```

or

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH);
```

Comment: The [doc](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH) says that value of `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH` is `2001`. I doubt I can set videoFrameRate as 2001. Can you elaborate your answer?